# Lambda in private VPC to cross-region DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-vpc

I have a lambda in a private isolated VPC in region A and a dynamoDB table in region B. Is it possible to query the table from the lambda without making the VPC public?

Comment: VPCs aren't private or public; subnets are.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you have associated the Lambda function with a VPC?

Answer (score 0):

One might thing you could peer VPCs across regions, keeping them private. However, DynamoDB uses a Gateway endpoint which does not support vpc peering:

> Endpoint connections cannot be extended out of a VPC. Resources on the other side of a VPN connection, VPC peering connection, transit gateway, or AWS Direct Connect connection in your VPC cannot use a gateway endpoint to communicate with DynamoDB.

You may be able to do something like call a Lambda in region B using peering, which contacts DynamoDB in its local region and returns the response to Lambda in region A.